# Getting an ouput of null on 2d array not sure where I went wrong

Tags: java

I have problem in my programing class and I am stuck at a point im not sure where to look to fix.

Here is the problem:

The World class will contain three private data fields. The first private data field is a 2
dimensional char array that represents the world. The size of the world will depend on what’s
passed to the constructor. The next private data field is a characterRow and the last private
data field is characterColumn.
The constructor will accept two values, width and height. Using width and height, set the size
of the 2 dimensional array. Then fill the array with a dash, -. The characterRow and
characterColumn data fields are both set to 0 and then place the character, ‘P’, at position
characterRow and characterColumn.
So if your world were to be printed with width 9, or 9 columns, and height 4, or 4 rows, it would
like something like this after creation:

```
P--------
---------
---------
---------
```

The world class will initially contain 5 public methods. These methods are moveUp,
moveDown, moveLeft, moveRight and displayWorld.

I am getting an ouput of:

```
Enter number of rows: 
9
Enter number of columns: 
9

P - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 
null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - null - 

 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
Commands can be UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, or EXIT. EXIT closes the program.
Enter command:
```

I can get to the points where the user enters the size of the array but then the array prints null with the character at the correct location then prints again correctly with no character.  I am unsure where I have gone off track here.  Can you please take a look and help me in any way?  My code for both classes are below

Driver class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    World world = new World();
    System.out.println("Commands can be UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, or EXIT. EXIT closes the program.");
    System.out.println("Enter command: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) 
    {
        String s = input.nextLine();

            switch (s) 
            {
                case "up":
                    world.moveUp();
                    world.displayWorld();
                    break;
                case "down":
                    world.moveDown();
                    world.displayWorld();
                    break;
                case "left":
                    world.moveLeft();
                    world.displayWorld();
                    break;
                case "right":
                    world.moveRight();
                    world.displayWorld();
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

World Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class World
{
private static final String  P = "P";
private String[][] array;
public World()
{        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
    int crow = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of columns: ");
    int ccol = input.nextInt();
    array = new String[crow][ccol];
    array[0][0]=P;
    displayWorld();   
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = new String();                    
            }
        }
    displayWorld();   
}

public void displayWorld()
{
    System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}

public void moveUp()
{
   for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
            {
                if (i < array.length - 1)
                {
                    array[i][j] = " - ";
                    array[i - 1][j] = P;
                }                    
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void moveDown()
{
    for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
            {
                if (i < array.length - 1)
                {
                    array[i][j] = " - ";
                    array[i + 1][j] = P;
                }                    
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void moveLeft()
{
    for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
            {
                if (i < array.length - 1)
                {
                    array[i][j] = " - ";
                    array[i][j - 1] = P;
                }                    
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}

public void moveRight()
{
    for(int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            if ((array[i][j]) == " - ")
            {
                if (i < array.length - 1)
                {
                    array[i][j] = " - ";
                    array[i][j + 1] = P;
                }                    
                return;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and answer your question for yourself

Comment: Okay so once you display the world for the first time your `array` is null at every location except `[0][0]` because you assign the value `P` to it. But then you go through and `wipe` the array with your for loops including the `P` because you do from `0 to 0` so that's why you are getting what you are getting. *THIS ALL HAPPENS INSIDE YOUR WORLD CONSTRUCTOR*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public World(){        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
    int crow = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of columns: ");
    int ccol = input.nextInt();
    array = new String[crow][ccol];
    //array[0][0]=P;
    //displayWorld();   
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                 array[i][j] = P;
                }else{
                 array[i][j] = new String();
                }                    
            }
        }
    displayWorld();   
    }
```

In the constructor, you have a displayWorld method call before filling your array. Then, when you are filling it, you re-fill your position [0][0] and the P disappears. By using the code that it's above, you'll get what you want.

I hope I have helped you!